How to POST and GET JSON Product objects including an Image using Spring Boot RESTful API?
I'm working on a Spring Boot application where I need to create a RESTful API to handle Product objects. Each Product object contains details like an image, product name, price, description, and other attributes. My goal is to:

POST a Product object in JSON format that includes the image, product name, price, description, etc.
GET the same Product object in JSON format from the server.

I'm encountering difficulties in handling the image within the JSON object. How should I structure my Product class, and what configurations or annotations do I need to use to properly handle the image data (likely as a base64 encoded string) along with other product details in the JSON object?
Entity Product Class

public class Product {
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private String description;
    private String image; 
}

Application Properties: Do I need any specific configuration in my application.properties for handling large JSON payloads or base64 encoded images?
Questions:

Handling Images: Is using a base64 encoded string for the image within the JSON object a good approach? If not, what are the recommended best practices?

Annotations and Configuration: What annotations or configurations do I need to handle the Product object correctly in both POST and GET requests, especially concerning the image data?

Improving the Code: Are there any improvements or best practices I should follow to make the API more efficient and maintainable?


Any example code snippets or references to relevant documentation would be highly appreciated. Thank you!
I structured my Product class to include the image as a base64 encoded string.
In my controller, I used @RequestBody to receive the Product object and @PathVariable to retrieve it by ID.
I tested posting a Product object with the image as a base64 encoded string using Postman.
What I Expected:
I expected to be able to POST a Product object with all details including the image, and then retrieve the same object using a GET request, with the image data intact.

You don't need to specifically convert the image to base64, you can use MultipartFile to receive the image.
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;    
public class Product {
   private String name;
   private double price;
   private String description;
   private MultipartFile image; 
   //getter,setter
}

then you can get the inputstream like this, and then you can write to disk.
@PostMapping("/upload")
public void uploadProduct(@ModelAttribute Product product) throws IOException {
   product.getImage().getInputStream();
}

and in javascript you can request like this:
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("name", "Product1");
formdata.append("image", fileInput.files[0], "C:\Users\user\Desktop\b072738f6e94413b7727e185d9816e6b.jpg");

var requestOptions = {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: myHeaders,
   body: formdata,
   redirect: 'follow'
};

Or in some tools, such as Postman, you can send a post request like this

